# Break long comments

Tags: ex-mode, comments, ex-command

Given the file *alfa.c*:

```
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, apeirian constituam interpretaris no his, soluta salutandi persequeris vel ne, facete impedit contentiones te eam. Ut utamur habemus qualisque usu
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  puts("hello world");
}
```

I would like to format all long comments to get results like this:

```
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, apeirian constituam interpretaris no his, soluta salutandi
// persequeris vel ne, facete impedit contentiones te eam. Ut utamur habemus qualisque usu
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  puts("hello world");
}
```

I see Vim has [an option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#format-comments) to format comments, however I did not see any Ex
mode commands. Is this possible?

Comment: GNU Indent is a workaround http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289360

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your configuration you can achieve the desired result with:

```
gq
```

If you want to use this as a ex command you can use:

```
normal! gqq
```

to format the current line.

Aslo, it's worth adding the flags `a` and `c` to your `'formatoption'` configuration:

```
set fo+=ac
```

This will try to preserve the current comment formatting as well as automatically formatting the paragraph.

You may want to have a look at:

- `:h format`
- `:h gq`
- `:h fo-table`
- `:h 'fo'`

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq

Answer (score 0):

You can set a limit for a line, like 80 columns for a line.

Then you can set a autocommand to split such lines whenever you save the file.

```
:au BufWrite *.* :%s#^\s\*//.\{78\}#&\r//#g
```

Put this in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I like this approach, but I can't get it to work @SibiCoder, `Pattern not found: .{80,}`. But even if it did it looks like this will take *anything* above 80 characters and turn it into a comment. This seems problematic.

Comment: What problems? Can you explain? I will refine my answer

Comment: 1st: I think you have one of the magic settings on (or off) for your regex. To make your regex work I get: `^\s*\/\/.\{78\}`. 2nd: if you had a line of code that was more than 80 characters, this would take it and turn it into a comment. Edit: I guess you fixed this issue by searching for `//`.

Comment: 3rd: This, of course only takes C-style comments into account. 4th: In the case where you have a REALLY long line (more than 160 characters) you will still end up with lines that are greater than 80.